# Robot Framework using proxy

Tags: proxy, robotframework

I have this curl call:

```
curl -k -i -X GET -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" --proxy1.0 "localhost:7070" "https://www.google.com"
```

I am trying to make a call with Robot Framework so i can test it with this same elements. This is what i got so far:

```
***Settings***
Library          Collections
Library          RequestsLibrary

***Variables***
${url}              http://www.google.com
${proxy}            localhost:7070
${headers}=         Create Dictionary     Cache-Control no-cache

***Test Cases***
Get Requests
   Create Session                      google      ${url}      ${headers}      ${proxy}
   ${resp}=                            Get Request        google  /
   Should Be Equal As Strings          ${resp.status_code}     200
```

I still get an error:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: I believe [this](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests) explains what you are after.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
***Variables***
...
${headers}=         Create Dictionary     Cache-Control no-cache
```

You cannot call keywords like `create dictionary` in the variables table. The above code is setting `${headers}` to be the *string* `"Create Dictionary Cache-Control no-cache"`.

Starting with version 2.9 of robot framework there is direct support for dictionaries using an ampersand rather than dollar sign for variables. You can specify values using `<key>=<value>` syntax. For example:

```
*** Variables ***
&{headers}    Cache-Control=no-cache
```